# Where was global scope in playframework and what are the benefits of it going away?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am reading that the playframework is removing global state that is in older 2.4.x versions.

Can someone explain where the global state currently is and what are the benefits of removing global state?

Comment: You might want to read these. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Highlights24
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24

Answer (score 1):

**What is the global state?**

There is an object `play.api.Play` with the following field:

```
@volatile private[play] var _currentApp: Application = _
```

**Where is it used?**

Whenever you do `Play.current` you refer to that single mutable global field. This is used all across the framework to access things such as:

- `play.api.Play.configuration` takes an implicit app
- `play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.defaultContext` calls the internal context, which uses the currently running app to get the actor system
- `play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system` takes an implicit app
- `play.api.libs.ws.WS.url` takes an implicit app
- and many more places..

**Why is that bad?**

A number of functions just take an implicit app, so that's not really global state, right? I mean, you could just pass in that app. However where do you get it from? Typically, people would import `play.api.Play.current`.

Another example: Let's say you want to develop a component that calls a webservice. What are the dependencies of such a class? The `WSClient`. Now if you want to get an instance of that, you need to call `play.api.libs.ws.WS.client` and pass in an application. So your pretty little component that logically only relies on a webservice client, now relies on the entire application.

Another big factor and a direct consequence of the previous point is testing. Let's say you want to test your webservice component. In theory, you'd only need to mock (or provide some dummy implementation of) the webservice client. However now that somewhere in your code you're calling `play.api.Play.current`, you need to make sure that that field is set at the time it is called. And the easiest way to ensure that is to start the play application. So you're starting an entire application just to test your little component.

Comment: isnt' global state now gone in the latest version of play?

Comment: The latest version is play 2.5, which deprecates `Play.current` (ie. the access to the current application). However there are still a few of places where it is used. Not relying on this anymore will incur API changes, which is why a number of "intermediate" releases are made towards the goal of becoming fully stateless (it that would be 3.0).